# Blender 3.0 alpha: Geometry Nodes deprecated node alternatives

Tags: geometry-nodes, conversion

I am working through geometry node tutorials and am finding nodes in version 3.0a that have already been deprecated within 2 weeks of a tutorial being uploaded along with, of course, the other 'legacy' nodes.

I would like to translate the old nodes to the new.  Is there documentation on alternative or replacement nodes that would help convert 2.9+ geo nodes to 3.0 - or even earlier versions of 3.0 to the most recent?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hello, I would suggest you wait until the official release which is due on the start of december. Until then there might be another batch of drastic changes which you would have to adapt to. Cheers

Comment: "*(...)have already been deprecated within 2 weeks of a tutorial being uploaded*" Such is the nature of alpha development software, if you plan to use it you have to learn how to deal with it. If you want stable documentation use current versions or wait for official releases

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.